# How to join topics with kafka stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

Kafka stream
I am trying to stream but I've some issues, it doesn't work. To get started, I have three connectors but I can't use my own keys. I need the keys to join them, right? How can I join with 2 or more keys?
I try to replicate something like this:
    select * from (select a. * from users a inner join deps b
    on a.dep = b.dep and a.group = b.group
    ) a inner join user_afy on a.id = b.id

I want to save the data the internal join in a topic and use it for the external join. This is an example I have.

Connector Properties:

```
....
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
mode=timestamp
query=select id, user, dep,tal, group,time from users
numeric.mapping=best_fit
table.types=TABLE
topic=users  
// I try use this with 1 or more fields but not worked  
transforms=createKey, extractInt  
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey  
transforms.createKey.fields=dep, group  
transforms.extractInt.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key  
transforms.extractInt.field=dep, group
```

standalone.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092  
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter  
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter  
key.converter.schemas.enable=false  
value.converter.schemas.enable=false  
offset.storage.file.filename=D:/tmp/connect.offsets  
plugin.path=D:/connector/lib
```

Topics:

```
Topic users    
{"id":"0001", "user":"Alex", "dep":"ofi", "postal":170, group="ingen",time:"xxx"}    
{"id":"0002", "user":"Emy", "dep":"lab", "postal":170, group="itn",time:"xxx"}    
{"id":"0003", "user":"Lea", "dep":"lab", "postal":170, group="itn",time:"xxx"}    
{"id":"0004", "user":"Silva", "dep":"cent", "postal":170, group="ingen",time:"xxx"}    
{"id":"0005", "user":"Foxy", "dep":"cent", "postal":170, group="ete",time:"xxx"}    

topic user_afy
{"id":"0001", name="bask"}
{"id":"0001", name="Silf"}
{"id":"0002", name="BTT"}
{"id":"0005", name="butf"}


Topic deps  
{"id_dep":"1", "dep":"ofi", "sind"="worker", "group"="ingen."}  
{"id_dep":"2", "dep":"lab", "sind"="worker", "group"="iti."}  
{"id_dep":"3", "dep":"cent", "sind"="worker", "group"="etc."}
```

My code is an example of the official website but I can't test it

```
public static void main(String[] Args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(......);

    final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
        final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);
        final Consumed<String, JsonNode> consumed = Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde);
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        final KStream<String, JsonNode> left = builder.stream("user", consumed);
        KTable<String, JsonNode> right = builder.table("deps", consumed);
        KStream<String, String> joined = left.join(right,
            (leftValue, rightValue) -> "left=" + leftValue + ", right=" + rightValue,
            Joined.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde, jsonSerde)
        );
//Edit
       joined.foreach((k, v) -> {
          System.out.println("key="+k+ ", val=" + v);
       });

}
```

The output, how would it show? To create a new topic, is a hashmap preferable with the values ​​you want to save in json format? Later I will create custom Serdes

Comment: You're never printing out the output of the steam. Try using a foreach and looking at the output. Or write a unit test to see if you're doing it correctly

Comment: Yes, I hadn't done it because I couldn't create the records since I can't create the keys..

Comment: Why not? You can use map function to set the key from the value. Also, latest kafka 2.4 let's you join without having both streams with same key

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "I can't use my own keys?". In Kafka Streams you can always set a new key as required for your processing.

If you want to read data into a KTable, you cannot change the key in a straightforward way though. You would need to read the topic as KStream, set a new key, and convert the KStream into a KTable (cf [Kafka Streams API: KStream to KTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937057/kafka-streams-api-kstream-to-ktable/)).

For multiple consecutive joins you can just "chain" the corresponding operations together.

```java
builder.stream("topic-1").selectKey(...).to("table-topic-1");
KTable t1 = builder.table("table-topic-1");

KStream firstJoinResult = builder.stream(...).selectKey(...).join(t1, ...).

builder.stream("topic-2").selectKey(...).to("table-topic-2");
KTable t2 = builder.table("table-topic-2");

firstJoinResult.selectKey(...).join(t2, ...).to("result-topic");
```